# Python retrieve specified nested JSON value

Tags: python, json, for-loop, nested-lists

I have a .json file with many entries looking like this:

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "time": "20220607T190731.442",
    "id": "123",
    "relatedIds": [
        {
            "id": "456",
            "source": "sourceA"
        },
        {
            "id": "789",
            "source": "sourceB"
        }
    ],
}
```

I am saving each entry in a python object, however, I only need the related ID from source A. Problem is, the related ID from source A is not always first place in that nested list.

So `data['relatedIds'][0]['id']` is not reliable to yield the right Id.

Currently I am solving the issue like this:

```
import json

with open("filepath", 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for value in data['relatedIds']:
    if(value['source'] == 'sourceA'):
        id_from_a = value['id']

entry = Entry(data['name'], data['time'], data['id'], id_from_a)
```

I don't think this approach is the optimal solution though, especially if relatedIds list gets longer and more entries appended to the JSON file.

Is there a more sophisticated way of singling out this 'id' value from a specified source without looping through all entries in that nested list?

Comment: are the related ids sorted? in any case you could add a `break` statement after you found it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a cleaner solution, you could try using python's `filter()` function with a simple lambda:

```
import json

with open("filepath", 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

filtered_data = filter(lambda a : a["source"] == "sourceA", data["relatedIds"])

id_from_a = next(filtered_data)['id']
entry = Entry(data['name'], data['time'], data['id'], id_from_a)
```

Correct me if I misunderstand how your json file looks, but it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

One step at a time, in order to get to all entries:

```py
>>> data["relatedIds"]
[{'id': '789', 'source': 'sourceB'}, {'id': '456', 'source': 'sourceA'}]
```

Next, in order to get only those entries with source=sourceA:

```py
>>> [e for e in data["relatedIds"] if e["source"] == "sourceA"]
[{'id': '456', 'source': 'sourceA'}]
```

Now, since you don't want the whole entry, but just the ID, we can go a little further:

```py
>>> [e["id"] for e in data["relatedIds"] if e["source"] == "sourceA"]
['456']
```

From there, just grab the first ID:

```py
>>> [e["id"] for e in data["relatedIds"] if e["source"] == "sourceA"][0]
'456'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you get whatever generates your .json file to produce the relatedIds as an object rather than a list?

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "time": "20220607T190731.442",
    "id": "123",
    "relatedIds": {
        "sourceA": "456",
        "sourceB": "789"
    }
}
```

If not, I'd say you're stuck looping through the list until you find what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible, as input is not created by a program I wrote/am responsible for